# Why does "Native module cannot be null" error occur when I import expo?

Tags: ios, macos, reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm using:

```
    react-native-cli: 2.0.1
    react-native: 0.48.3
    npm: 4.6.1
    expo: 20.1.3
```

React Native App is created by command: `react-native init`

And I have used both `react-native link` and `react-native link expo` commands

Here comes the problem, every time I import expo like so

```
    import { Permissions } from 'expo';
```

Or

```
    const Expo = require('expo');
```

I get this error:
[image]

BTW, I'm using mac

Comment: Did you re-run using `react-native run-ios` instead of refreshing? A link requires a complete rebuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you review this solution in the issues

https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/160

https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/279

in some case reinstall node_modules, clear all caches could help