# Native Module cannot be null (ios) - Expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-ios

I am developing a Expo-managed (not bare) mobile application. I recently ran into this issue: **it crashes on start on ios**. and I understand that this has to do with some of my packages requiring ios native modules, therefor I have to eject before I can use this package.

However, my goal here is not to eject but to find the package causing this issue, however, unable find it so far.

What suprises me is that android runs without issues, even though it looks like it requires native modules.

**Please note everything runs fine on android**

**Error**
[image]

**package.json**

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.0",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^3.1.9",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "~1.12.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "3.0.4",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.9.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.3",
    "expo": "^40.0.0",
    "expo-asset": "~8.2.1",
    "expo-av": "~8.7.0",
    "expo-camera": "~9.1.0",
    "expo-constants": "~9.3.3",
    "expo-document-picker": "~8.4.1",
    "expo-file-system": "~9.3.0",
    "expo-font": "~8.4.0",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~8.4.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~9.2.0",
    "expo-linking": "~2.0.0",
    "expo-media-library": "~10.0.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.8.2",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.8.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "expo-web-browser": "~8.6.0",
    "i": "^0.3.6",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "npm": "^6.14.9",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^4.0.4",
    "react-native-audio-record": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-image-view": "^2.1.9",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.15.0",
    "react-native-spinkit": "^1.5.1",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.5.0",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^1.3.4",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.3",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^2.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "@types/react": "~16.9.35",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.63.2",
    "babel-preset-expo": "8.3.0",
    "jest-expo": "^40.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

**Line 4 of MessagesScreen.tsx**: `import AppHeader from '../components/AppBar';`
**AppHeader.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Appbar, Divider, Menu } from 'react-native-paper';
import { AppStyles } from '../AppStyles';
import { INav } from '../models/INav';
import { NavigationUtil } from '../utils/NavigationUtil';
import { ListenerPersona } from './Persona';

export interface AppHeaderProps {
    title: string;
    actions?: any[];
}

class AppHeader extends React.Component<AppHeaderProps & INav, { menuShown: boolean }>
{
    constructor(p: any) {
        super(p);
        this.state = { menuShown: false }
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <Appbar.Header style={{ backgroundColor: AppStyles.color.tint }}>
                <Appbar.Content title={this.props.title} color={AppStyles.color.white} />
                {
                    this.props.actions
                }
                <Menu
                    visible={this.state.menuShown}
                    onDismiss={() => this.setState({ menuShown: false })}
                    anchor={<Appbar.Action color={'white'} icon="dots-vertical" onPress={() => this.setState({ menuShown: true })} />}>
                    <Menu.Item icon={() => <ListenerPersona size={30} />} onPress={() => { }} title="Account" />
                    <Divider />
                    <Menu.Item icon="exit-to-app" onPress={() => {
                        NavigationUtil.reset(this.props.navigation, [{
                            name: 'Login',
                            params: { disableAutoLogin: true }
                        }])
                    }} title="Logout" />
                </Menu>
            </Appbar.Header>
        );
    }
}

export default AppHeader;
```

Comment: Can you please show code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46188078/13789135 this may help

Comment: _What suprises me is that android runs without issues, even though it looks like it requires native modules._

it might be that some functionality requires native modules in ios but not android

Comment: @arturgrzesiak: That would explain indeed, thank you. Any idea on hwo to find the package requiring the native modules? I think I checked all of them already

Comment: what is line 4 of `screens/MessagesScreen.tsx`?

Comment: @arturgrzesiak: import AppHeader from '../components/AppBar';`
 I updated the post with the appheader component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution 1:

Solution by @Nick Prozee he got the issue from `react-native-audio-record`

> Well basically that is a pain in the ***. What I did is outlined all
> my components 1 by 1 to narrow down which one was causing the error.
> This led me to the package react-native-audio-record. The problem is
> that the details you get from expo, are wrong, I did not find any
> logical way to approach this issue rather then outlining all of my
> code until error disappears

## Solution 2:

it has a bug in react native which is not resolved yet

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26813

can you try it with `remote debugging mode`? because it is working with remote debugging mode yet.

Comment: Im not debugging the remote JS. I use the expo client on device without the remote debugging enabled. **PS**: As so to your comment, I tried both with same result

Comment: @NickProzee can you add any reproducible example repo so I can fix it for you?

Comment: @MuhammadNuman: Yes I will try to do this asap and report back to you. The problem is I have a GPDR on this.

Comment: @MuhammadNuman: By creating the reproducable demo, I found the package causing it. It is being caused by `react-native-audio-record`. Please provide this as the answer so I can award you the points. You put me on the right track.

Comment: The stacktrace that I got from the expo client did put me on the wrong track...

Comment: @NickProzee can you elaborate on how you fix this so I can add your answer to my answer

Comment: @MuhammadNuman Well basically that is a pain in the ***. What I did is outlined all my components 1 by 1 to narrow down which one was causing the error. This led me to the package `react-native-audio-record`. The problem is that the details you get from expo, are wrong, I did not find any logical way to approach this issue rather then outlining all of my code until error disappears...